# How do i get result by comparing Date column and Time column when Date and Time column are separate columns in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to fetch events based on their `end_date` and `end_time` from `events` table. So i need to fetch those events only which are in the future. So if current date and time is greater than `end_date` and `end_time` then then it should not fetch those records because the the date and time has passed.

I have done so far :

```
$today = Carbon::now();

return $query->where('end_date', '>=', today()->format('Y-m-d'))
            ->where('end_time', '>=', $today->toTimeString());
```

But this code will not work as expected.

Lets suppose The record is `end_date = 2020-02-05` and `end_time = 08:00:00` and right now it's `20:10:00` in my town. So As i can see this is a future record and i want it to be fetched but it will not fetch because of `where('end_time)` because `08:00:00 >= 20:10:00` is `false` hence this solution will not work

How can i write a query where i will be able to check first if date is today then only check time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why on earth are you using two columns and not a single datetime column?  Anyway, what results are you getting?  None?  Rows that shouldn't match?  Give us some detail please.

Comment: What field types are you using for `end_date` and `end_time`?

Comment: @ChuckAdams getting those records which time is not greater than now.

Comment: @Rwd for `end_date` `Date` and for `end_time` using `Time`

Comment: Can you post a few sample data rows?

Comment: For example: i have a record with the data `end_date = 2020-02-04 ` and `end_time = 19:42:00`. And right now in my town its `20:00`. So here i don't want this record to be fetched because the time is already passed. But using above code it's gives me this record also.

Comment: @mdexp No thats not an issue ( I am pretty sure ). I have updated my question. Please have a look. It is causing problem because of `where` clause

Comment: Can't you use a single column in the database by storing a DATETIME value instead of two separated columns?

Comment: That i had to think long back. Now it's too late :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to combine the two fields at a database level (assuming you are using MySql):

```php
return $query->whereRaw('TIMESTAMP(`end_date`,`end_time`) >= ?', [now()->toDateTimeString()]);
```

Comment: That's nice to hear. By the way if you have the opportunity I really suggest you to fix the database to use a single column. You could do that as a two step process to merge the current records into a new `ended_at` column and then remove the two old columns after everything else is fixed.

Comment: Yes definitely i will look into it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the two columns and use just one column of the type datetime and then you can get the date or the time in the code